# How do I write a program to produce properly quoted command line arguments for another program?

Tags: bash, quotes

I need to write a program whose output is part of a command line for another program. e.g.

```
% helper
--arg1='foo bar' --arg2='another string'
```

which is then used as

```
% program `helper`
```

or

```
% program args `helper` more-args
```

It's simple enough without quotes, but I can't find any sort of quoting that will work.

I can get it to work like this :

```
% echo `helper` | xargs program
```

but I don't want to inflict that sort of thing on my customers.

Is there anything that 'helper' can output that will allow 'program' to be called in a simpler way than by using xargs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work.

```
# Make helper output an array assignment
% helper
options=( --arg1='foo bar' --arg2='another string' )

# Use eval to actually define the array using the output of helper
% eval "$(helper)"
% echo "${options[0]}"
--arg1='foo bar'

# Call program using options instead of helper directly
% program "${options[@]}"
```

Quoting is part of the shell syntax, and you cannot have shell syntax embedded in parameters. You could also try

```
% eval "program $(helper)"
```

although I recommend against such broader use of `eval`. As with any use of `eval`, you need to be careful with what `helper` outputs, so that no unintended code is run.